# Android Reprint Library isHardwarePresent Returns False on Some Devices

Tags: java, android, fingerprint

I'm using Reprint library for fingerprint authentication. But Reprint.isHardwarePresent() method returns false on some fingerprint supported devices.

```
if (Reprint.isHardwarePresent() && Reprint.hasFingerprintRegistered()) {
            Reprint.authenticate(new AuthenticationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int moduleTag) {
                    numpad.setDesc(getString(R.string.success_fingerprint));
                    startActivity(new Intent(SigninActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(AuthenticationFailureReason failureReason, boolean fatal, CharSequence errorMessage, int moduleTag, int errorCode) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fingerprint Error :"+errorMessage.toString());
                    if(prefHelper.isVibrateWhenWrong()) feedbackHelper.vibrateNorm();
                    ivFingerPrint.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWrong), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            ivFingerPrint.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
            });
        }
```

And my second problem, sometimes Reprint.Authenticate not starting. It's logging this

```
V/FingerprintService: handleError(client=mypackagename, error = 5)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: On which devices for instance ? manufacturer + model + api version

Comment: some Google Pixel, Samsung S7 devices @LaurentY